# SQL combine two tables into one table based on the instruction of a third table

Tags: sql-server

Simplified problem with minimal information is as follows:

I have 2 source tables:

Table A:

```
Col:  1   2   3   4   5 
Data: 18  15  16  17  10
```

Table B:

```
Col:  1   2   3   4   5 
Data: 81  51  61  71  99
```

And a third table that contains "instructions":

Table 3:

```
ID   Source
1     A
2     A
3     B
4     A
5     B
```

Based on what Table 3 tells me, I need to pick values from table A and B, to form a result table:

```
Col:  1   2   3   4   5 
Data: 18  15  61  17  99
```

Comment: what relates the two rows to each other?

Comment: @JChao Table A and Table B each only contains one row. They are independent, only with shared column ID (i.e. 1 to 5).

Comment: Do you know about the CASE expression in SQL?

Comment: @TabAlleman I do... but the actual data has more than 5 things - not in the millions, but about 30-40... I thought listing 5 in the question would be sufficient to say "we may not want to copy paste a hardcoded line 5 times, unless we have to."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

**Schema**

```
create table TableA (col int, data1 int);
create table TableB (col int, data1 int);
create table TableC (col int, Source1 varchar(100));

insert into TableA values (1, 18), (2, 15), (3, 16);
insert into TableB values (1, 81), (2, 51), (3, 61);

insert into TableC values (1, 'A'), (2, 'A'), (3, 'B');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT o.col
    ,CASE 
        WHEN o.Source1 = 'A'
            THEN a.data1
        ELSE b.data1
        END data
FROM TableC o
LEFT JOIN TableA a ON o.col = a.col
    AND o.Source1 = 'A'
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON o.col = b.col
    AND o.Source1 = 'B'
```

**Result**

```
Col   Data
---------
1     18
2     15
3     61
```

**----------Updated---------**

Okay, as per the discussion, you need to use dynamic query. You need to first construct columns from `tablec` and then use it dynamic query as shown below.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((
            SELECT CASE 
                    WHEN c.Source1 = 'A'
                        THEN ',' + 'a.[' + cast(c.Col AS VARCHAR(4)) + ']'
                    ELSE ',' + 'b.[' + cast(c.Col AS VARCHAR(4)) + ']'
                    END
            FROM TableC c
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM TableA a
                    FULL OUTER JOIN TableB b ON 1 = 1'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query;
```

**Result**

```
1   2    3   4
--------------
18  15   61  17
```

Comment: Thanks, but Table A, B, and result table are horizontal, they only contain one row of data.

Comment: @user1032613: you mean 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. are table column name not record itself ?? Can you show us your table structure with some sample records ?

Comment: That is what I mean, those are column names. Thanks for the time so far, have an appreciation upvote :)

Comment: @user1032613: I think you might need dynamic pivoting here. Let me try to create your scenario in my laptop.

Comment: @user1032613: I got the solution. see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way but this works.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (SELECT Source FROM Table3 WHERE ID = 1) = 'A' THEN a.[1] ELSE b.[1] END
    , CASE WHEN (SELECT Source FROM Table3 WHERE ID = 2) = 'A' THEN a.[2] ELSE b.[2] END
    , CASE WHEN (SELECT Source FROM Table3 WHERE ID = 3) = 'A' THEN a.[3] ELSE b.[3] END
    , CASE WHEN (SELECT Source FROM Table3 WHERE ID = 4) = 'A' THEN a.[4] ELSE b.[4] END
    , CASE WHEN (SELECT Source FROM Table3 WHERE ID = 5) = 'A' THEN a.[5] ELSE b.[5] END
FROM dbo.TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON 1=1
```

Comment: Thank you, this definitely works. Have an appreciation upvote :)